# How to pass a display:column parameter to controller in spring?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, displaytag

I am trying to pass a parameter value from the list in display table, I tried onclick for the href but it's throwing an error called attribute onclick is not available in displaytag. I even tried with id, no luck.

How do I pass this value to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

```
<display:column>
<a onclick="fn()">link</a>
</display:column>
```

Comment: <display:column property="partno" paramId="action" sortable="true" title="Part No" maxLength="40">
   <a onclick="jobidfn()">property="partno"</a>
   </display:column>

Comment: Remove property="partno" in display:column. Probably you will need <a onclick="jobidfn()"><c:out value="${row.partno}"/></a> where row is from <display:table id="row">

Comment: how do I get the value from db? if I remove the property attribute?

Comment: See comment above. ${row.partno} where row is id of your table.